# How to enable transparent on screen keys in app on Android Lollipop?

Tags: android

I saw this in a flashlight app on my nexus 5 the other day running Lollipop, and I now really want to implement it in some of the apps I am developing, but I can't seem to find any resources saying how to enable the transparent navigation keys.

This is what I mean:
[image]

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be hugely grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme add the following line:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Check out iosched(I/O 14) app in github which describes the API to use.

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks heaps, Corey :)